# Python - How to use attributes of one method in another method

Tags: python

Assume this class...

```
Class feed(object):

    def __init__ (self, food=0) :
        self.food = food
    def fill(self, water = 0): 
        self.food +=1
        self.water +=1
```

How can i create another method that will make use of 'water', the attribute of 'fill' method without including water in the constructor method

Comment: Have you just *tried doing that*? If you have methods using attributes that weren't defined in `__init__`, what if they're run in a different order to the one you expect? Also, note that it's `class` (Python is case-sensitive) and you should read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: The question is completely unclear to me.

Comment: @timegeb it's as simple as this... create another method and find a way to include 'water'(attribute of method 'fill') attribute in the method

Comment: The `self` refers to the "instance" that all methods share.

Comment: @Qudus `fill` does not have an attribute `water`, your instance of `feed` has (or has not, if `fill` has never been called).

Comment: @timegeb so attributes belongs to classes only, methods are just some means of carrying them out?

Comment: @Qudus well... sort of. There's a difference between a class and an instance of a class. Methods are just functions associated with a class - roughly speaking. To further confuse you: functions are objects themselves, so they can have attributes, too. I'd say you should look at some object oriented programming tutorial for python, the comment section is not a good place to explain it all.

Comment: Will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once you declare `self.food` or `self.water`, these are attributes of the *whole object*, not just the method they were declared in. As long as you parse `self` to a new method of a class, it can access all of the attributes of the object by referencing `self.food`, `self.water`, etc. E.g.:

```
class feed(object):

    # other functions

    def new_method(self):
        #This can now reference other object attributes
```

However, as pointed out by @jonrsharpe in the comments, make sure that the order in which the methods are run does not result in a method trying to reference an attribute that has not been declared yet. It is good practice to define all attributes in the `__init__` method of a class. Currently, you don't declare `self.water` before calling `self.water += 1`, which will raise an `AttributeError` due to the attribute `self.water` being referenced before assignment. Here's a way to stop this:

```
class feed(object):

    def __init__ (self, food = 0, water = 0) :
        self.food = food
        self.water = water

    def fill(self): 
        self.food += 1
        self.water += 1
```

Comment: Well, you *could* catch an AttributeError

Answer (score 0):

class feed(object):

```
def __init__ (self, food = 0, water = 0) :
    self.food = food
    self.water = water
def meth(self,x=1)
    self.attr = x
def fill(self): 
    self.food += 1
    self.water += 1
    print(self.attr)
```

-----------------------------------------> The answer that @Rob Murray gave the order also does not matter now and the attribute can be called from a method that is not a constructor method.